# WeasyPrint chooses the wrong font cut

Tags: fonts, weasyprint

I thought I finally found the right HTML to PDF creator with WeasyPrint. However I have a problem with the font that I'm using. In the CSS I specified "Nimbus Sans Novus T OT" as the font. I generate the PDF with the following command:

```
$ weasyprint 'http://localhost/test.html' output.pdf
```

When I generate the PDF it always uses the condensed cut of the font altough I didn't specify `font-stretch` (specifying it in css doesn't help). How can I specify which cut it should use? Why doesn't it just use the regular cut?

Is there a special directory where I can place fonts for WeasyPrint? Maybe this way I could rename the fonts specify them this way. (I'm using OX X Mavericks.)

Comment: It finds the right cut when I disable the condensed cut of that particular weight but I can't disable them because I need them for other apps.

Comment: I tried renaming the font. It worked for 2 cuts. However I can't get the 3rd one working correctly.